# GeoDjango Bounding Box Filter with top and bottom coordinates

Tags: django, geodjango

I'm creating a GEO app with Google Maps and I receive bounding box as 2 coordinates:
Top Left(top_lat,top_long) and Bottom Right (bot_lat, bot_long)

I have a model with PointField.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    location        = models.PointField()
```

Create a bounding box tuple:

```
    bbox = (top_lat,top_long, bot_lat, bot_long)
    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)
```

I using the bounding box geometry:

```
    shops = Shop.objects.filter(location__bbcontains=geom)
```

But not find any coordinates, although there are some coordinates. 
Please help me solve problems. Thanks

Comment: "bbox = (top_lat,top_long, bot_lat, bot_long)" - please note that from_bbox accepts (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), and X is longitude, Y is latitude, so it's actually (lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max).

Answer (score 2):

You should use "within" lookup:

```
shops = Shop.objects.filter(location__within=geom)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your filter is incorrect.

`location__bbcontains=geom` means that you geometry field (location, which is point) bounding box must contain bounding box you created (geom, which is polygon). And that is pretty much false every time since your polygon is bigger than bbox for a single point.

You're looking to have: `location__inside=geom` which returns locations that are inside geom.